# font files doesn't render in angular2

Tags: css, angular, fonts, angular-cli

i add font files in assets/font folder and then i create bellow css file named `fontiran.css`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('.//iran.font/eot/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Bold.eot');
    src: url('./iran.font/eot/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
         url('./iran.font/woff2/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),  /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
         url('./iran.font/woff/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Bold.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
         url('./iran.font/ttf/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url('./iran.font/eot/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Medium.eot');
    src: url('./iran.font/eot/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
         url('./iran.font/woff2/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),  /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
         url('./iran.font/woff/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Medium.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
         url('./iran.font/ttf/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('./iran.font/eot/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Light.eot');
    src: url('./iran.font/eot/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
         url('./iran.font/woff2/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Light.woff2') format('woff2'),  /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
         url('./iran.font/woff/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Light.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
         url('./iran.font/ttf/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    src: url('./iran.font/eot/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_UltraLight.eot');
    src: url('./iran.font/eot/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_UltraLight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
         url('./iran.font/woff2/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_UltraLight.woff2') format('woff2'),  /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
         url('./iran.font/woff/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_UltraLight.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
         url('./iran.font/ttf/IRANSansWeb(FaNum)_UltraLight.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('./iran.font/eot/IRANSansWeb(FaNum).eot');
    src: url('./iran.font/eot/IRANSansWeb(FaNum).eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  /* IE6-8 */
         url('./iran.font/woff2/IRANSansWeb(FaNum).woff2') format('woff2'),  /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
         url('./iran.font/woff/IRANSansWeb(FaNum).woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
         url('./iran.font/ttf/IRANSansWeb(FaNum).ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and then add the style sheet file to `angular-cli.json` :

```
"styles": [  
     ...
        "./assets/font/fontiran.css",
     ...
         "styles.css"    

      ],
```

and then add font-family name to body:

```
body{
font-family:font-family: IRANSans;
}
```

in run time I inspect element and i see fontirans.css was rendered but in network tab i didn't see ttf and eot and woff files .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an option is to use base64 encode .
go to site https://transfonter.org/ and upload fonts, check Base64 encode.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

show must put folder fonts in folder assets then you use from fonts.
folder assets is for files image and font .